# ROOT installation on mac OS El Capitan in Continuous Integration

Tags: python, ruby, macos

After ROOT installation using brew on mac OS El Capitan with the following code from travis file:

```
brew update > /dev/null;
brew install xz;
brew install homebrew/science/root;
source $(brew --prefix root)/libexec/thisroot.sh;
```

the following error occurs (build https://travis-ci.org/yandex/rep/jobs/168399771):

```
/usr/local/opt/root/libexec/thisroot.sh: line 45: shell_session_update: command not found
```

This leads to an error of importing ROOT in python:

```
python -c 'import ROOT'
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
```

The source of the error, maybe, is the [rvm](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3540). The following recipes of adding ([first](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3540), [second](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/issues/210))

```
echo 'shell_session_update' > $HOME/.bash_logout;
```

or

```
echo 'shell_session_update() { :; }' > $HOME/.direnvrc;
```

both do not work.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this? Thanks in advance.